# WCF Streaming with authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, streaming

I have a WCF service which must be secured with Windows and Certificate authentication.
I know that wsHttpBinding does no support Streaming but [according to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx) it can be done using transport security with a customBinding but I am not able to do it...

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="AuthBinding">
      <mtomMessageEncoding maxBufferSize="65535" />
      <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="Sign"/>
      <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I am going from one exception to another :

> The security capabilities of binding 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding' do not match those of the generated runtime object. Most likely this means the binding contains a StreamSecurityBindingElement, but lacks a TransportBindingElement that supports Stream Security

Or

> The request message must be protected. This is required by an operation of the contract ('IEntity','WebService.Entity'). The protection must be provided by the binding ('CustomBinding','WebService.Entity')

Comment: What actual problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than being done in a single step, this is two step process.

1. Enable Transport Security with Certificate Authentication.
2. Enable Transport Security with Windows Authentication.

Also I am not sure both works together.

But MSDN Article found seems to direct in a correct direction:

[**How to: Secure a Service with Windows Credentials with wsHttpBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734673%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please refer these links from MSDN for further learning (not much help if you are in hurry to deliver some milestone):

[Transport Security with Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

**Update**

You have to use custom binding having Mixed (transport with message credentials) security mode.

Three binding elements relate to message level security, all of which derive from the `SecurityBindingElement` class.

The three are `TransportSecurityBindingElement`, SymmetricSecurityBindingElement, and `AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement`. The `TransportSecurityBindingElement` is used to provide **Mixed mode security**. The other two elements are used when the message layer provides security.
Additional classes are used when transport level security is provided:

```
HttpsTransportBindingElement  
SslStreamSecurityBindingElement 
WindowsStreamSecurityBindingElement
```

You can get help on:

[How to: Create a Custom Binding Using the SecurityBindingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and

[Security Capabilities with Custom Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: wsHttpBinding does not allow using Streaming, I have to use a customBinding, but it is tricky

Comment: yes, tricky & quite time taking one if you are doing it first time.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basic"  transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```